# Where does the actual java code reside if I export my jar without the source file?

Tags: java, jar

I am familiar with the jar structure and it will have a .class files in the classes directory as well as `META-INF` directory containing the information to `main()`.

But where does the actual java code resides in a jar? 
Does it resides a compiled byte code? But don't different machines have different compilers?

I know that I can extract the java code using a decompiler which might be illegal. But I am not interested in doing so. I am more interested in understanding how code is stored? 
Is it encrypted? If so, what is the encryption algorithm? what is the location inside the jar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JAR file is just a ZIP file, renamed to mean Java ARchive.
You can check what's inside, unzipping it. If you're on a OS that doesn't allow you to decompress that archive because doesn't appear to be a compressed file, just change the extension to ZIP.
JAR files are not encrypted.

Java Sources are compiled in a platform-neutral **Java bytecode**, that's a kind of intermediate binary.
Once JVM load the classes it either interprets the ***bytecode*** or ***just-in-time*** compiles it to the underlying machine. JARs usually only contain that ***bytecode***

Usually sources are not included in the JARs, especially for distribution. Some projects deliver sources as well in a separate archive. You should check with the provider of the JAR you're dealing with to get sources.

If decompiling is illegal or not depends on the terms of the license applied to JAR. You should check those.
Decompiling a class object is not a very easy task, but a guy used to do a very good job with his JAD.
Unfortunately it's no more maintained, but there are some websites where you can still download it.
Decompiled classes will not look exactly as the real sources, and you could have to make some changes, but you'll definitely get an idea about the source.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you specify otherwise, the source code is *not* included in the JAR file. The JAR file normally only contain class files (compiled JVM instructions), not source code.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. How can the jar serve its function without the actual code? There must be the actual code inside the jar in some format? And how can a decompiler extract the code if it is not there?

Comment: @rents See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode - unlike an "interpreted" language, Java is *compiled* to special byte-code which is later run by a JVM. A decompiler can *only* extract from what is present; things like local variable names (which are not parameters), formatting, and comments are lost, for instance. A "good" decompiler will try and reconstruct as much as possible given context, but it is still a lossy source -> bytecode -> source transformation.

Comment: Ok. So what you are saying is that the source code is stored as the java bytecode which can be run by different JVMs of different machines. But where is it stored physically inside the jar?

Comment: @rents No, the **bytecode** is stored in .class files (in JARs). *The original source code (in the .java) files is gone*. In this way Java is like C (only it compiles to a well-defined IL and not a specific machine target).

Comment: Oh, so the code(method definitions etc without the body) in .class files is stored as text which I can see if I extract the jar. But it also contains the java bytecode for that class. Am I correct?

Comment: @rents No, the **bytecode** in a .class file is *not* text and is *not* human-readable. Some programs can *reconstruct* (eg. decompile) equivalent "Java source" from **bytecode**, but it is merely a *reconstruction* with equivalent semantics and *not* the original source. That is, the source (original "Java code") is *not* normally present in a JAR - at all - but merely the *compiled* **bytecode**.

Comment: I mean the method definition etc which I can see if I open the .class with a text editor.

Comment: @rents Yes, the class definition (including method names) is part of the bytecode. (Note that most of what is in a .class file will look like gibberish when opened with a normal text editor.)